# Fixnum#to_s performance issue

Tags: ruby

I have the following algorithm (it searches for palindromes whose binary representation is also a palindrome):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
class Runner
  attr_accessor :min, :max, :sum

  def initialize(min, max)
    @sum = 0
    @min, @max = min, max
  end

  def run
    current = @min
    while current <= @max
      string = current.to_s
      if string == string.reverse && current.to_s(2) == current.to_s(2).reverse
        @sum += current
      end
      current += 1
    end
    puts @sum
  end
end

t1 = Time.now
Runner.new(*ARGV.first.split(/\.+/).map(&:to_i)).run
puts "Time spent: #{(Time.now - t1).round(2)} s."
```

I run it for a `10..10_000_000` range. The version I provided above results in:

```
Time spent: 2.55 s.
```

But if I change

```
    while current <= @max
      string = current.to_s
      if string == string.reverse && current.to_s(2) == current.to_s(2).reverse
```

to

```
    while current <= @max
      string = current.to_s
      string_b = current.to_s(2)
      if string == string.reverse && string_b == string_b.reverse
```

then I get

```
Time spent: 6.25 s.
```

While I would expect it to be faster (less calculations required) it is twice slower. At the same time #to_s without an argument works as expected and if I remove the variable and perform calculations twice:

```
    while current <= @max
      if current.to_s == current.to_s.reverse && current.to_s(2) == current.to_s(2).reverse
```

then it works slower

```
Time spent: 4.17 s.
```

Looking at the [source of #to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) doesn't help to understand it except the problem is related to the `else` branch of condition. But I can't find an issue in [rb_scan_args](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/cf0a8d28415c14b593662f4f951e713063e5ffc3/lib/rdoc/parser/c.rb#L1117) or [NUM2INT](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?v=2.1.1;i=NUM2INT) either. Can anyone explain why it works this way (I use MRI 2.1.1p76)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby when you have an expression like

```
a && b
```

`a` is evaluated first and, if false, `b` is not evaluated.

Base10 palindromes are rare, so for the vast majority of your cycles through the loop, the original code checks only that `string == string.reverse` is false and then continues to the next iteration of the loop. Thus you only do the `to_s` once and the pair of `to_s(2)` almost never.

The other sets of changes all call `to_s` more frequently, and thus do more work and consequently are slower. Doesn't seem so surprising to me.

Comment: Ah, of course! No surprise at all! I wrote the script some time ago and later when I opened the file I didn't take `&&` into account for some reason and started thinking there's something wrong. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

In your original version, `current.to_s(2)` is only calculated if `string == string.reverse`, because `&&` short-circuits. The equivalent would be:

```
while current <= @max
  string = current.to_s
  if string == string.reverse
    string_b = current.to_s(2)
    if string_b == string_b.reverse
```

Comment: trushkevich, can you report the time for this modification? My guess is 2.52s.

Comment: minitech, yeah I overlooked it. When I wrote the script I've been thinking right about this of course. Sorry, I accepted Todd Agulnick's just because his reputation is lower.

Comment: Cary Swoveland, it's hard to tell correctly for only 1 script run, it varies from `2.48s.` to `2.62s.`.

Comment: I think the conclusion is that the addition of the line `string_b = current.to_s(2)` makes very little difference.  You got three good answers, lucky you.

Answer (score 2):

Analyzing this code in a profiler, it seems the the majority of the time is spent inside of the `fix_to_s()` C call.

[image: fix_to_s]

Jumping into the assembly code of `fix_to_s()` we see that is spends the majority of its time on a single instruction `movslq %edx, %rdx`. Apparently, `movslq` is moves a long (32bit) into a quad (64bit).

[image: movslq]

In the version of your code with `string2` being memoized, we have 3027 samples of the `movslq`, while in the non-memoized version we have only 700 samples! What gives?

It seems that in the memoized version, MORE string objects are being allocated, and thus freed by the ruby interpreter. Notice the time spent creating and freeing string objects.

[image: allocating-strings]

I ran some stats on object allocation using the `allocation_stats` gem, and they show that there are INDEED less strings being allocated in the non-memoized version. About 2/3 the amount.

`test.rb     String       20032954`

vs.

`test.rb     String       30010967`

When you explicitly set `string2 = current.to_s(2)` they have to allocate memory for you, as you *may* need it. However, in your code it will not necessarily ever have to execute the 2nd part of the `&&` statement, so you avoid that allocation altogether.

Obviously, increasing the amount of allocations will slow things down in a number ways, including make cache misses more likely, more garbage collection, and more `free()`ing and `malloc()`ing which explains why the relationship of allocations/time is not linear.

Comment: Helpful, and pleasing to the eye.